# How to make a customizad method python?

Tags: python, methods

This might be a dumb question but I'm a beginner, how do you make your own method in python
Example the method list.clear() i want to make one that does that but it says list.NUKE
Thank you for the help!
So for example I installed colorama if you color of text you type in Fore.RED()

I want to do this with my own command

Comment: Are you asking how to add methods to an existing, built-in class? Generally, Python does not support this, although it is *possible* using various hacks. Normally, you would just subclass `list` and add your own method to the subclass though

Comment: @JNevill the answer to that duplicate will not work for lists.

Comment: Just to help you in the future, there's a big difference between customizing a library class and customizing a built-in type.  You can modify objects when they are loaded from source, but not the built-in types.

Comment: @TimRoberts how do you modify when they are loaded from source thx